# Sitecore Solr index updating - my index reverts back

Tags: solr, sitecore

All,

I am currently having an issue where I reindex and the index gets updated for a couple of minutes and then reverts back to the previous index. The only thing I see in the log is this: 11:43:59    WARN    SolrCore    [sitecore] PERFORMANCE WARNING: Overlapping onDeckSearchers=2

**UPDATE:**

Here is the requested information:

Sitecore Version: 7.0

Comment: Can you paste relevant SOLR bits of your index configuration, please?

Comment: Oh, and Sitecore version information as well, please

Comment: What exactly do you mean by relevant solr bits? You mean the sitecore solr config?